# SQL if not exists insert else update

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I Have a stored procedure that works below:

```
--Stored procedure to update data in Data_Archive.dbo.company
CREATE PROC dbo.TransferCompanyInfo
as
BEGIN TRAN
INSERT INTO Data_Archive.dbo.Company
Select 
CompanyID,
CompanyName,
Address1,
Address2,
Address3,
Address4,
ZipCode,
FROM OLD.dbo.company 
where not exists (select Data_Archive.dbo.Company.CompanyID from                   Data_Archive.dbo.Company
WHERE CompanyID = OLD.dbo.Company.CompanyID)

Update Data_Archive.dbo.Company
Set 
Data_Archive.dbo.Company.CompanyID = b.CompanyID,
Data_Archive.dbo.Company.CompanyName = b.CompanyName,
Data_Archive.dbo.Company.Address1 = b.Address1,
Data_Archive.dbo.Company.Address2 = b.Address2,
Data_Archive.dbo.Company.Address3 = b.Address3,
Data_Archive.dbo.Company.Address4 = b.Address4,
Data_Archive.dbo.Company.ZipCode = b.ZipCode,
From Data_Archive.dbo.Company a, OLD.dbo.Company b
Where a.CompanyID = b.CompanyID


IF @@ERROR <> 0
            BEGIN
                ROLLBACK TRAN
                RAISERROR ('Error occured while copying data to TachographData_Archive.dbo.company', 16, 1)
                RETURN -1
           END

 IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
     BEGIN
           COMMIT TRAN
           RETURN 0
     END
```

However I was wondering how could I make it faster because at the moment it has to scan table to see if not exists, then insert, then scan again and update. I was thinking if instead I did if exists update else insert it would make it faster but I'm not sure how to reformat it. At the moment I tried the code below but doesn't work:

--Stored procedure to update data in Data_Archive.dbo.company

```
 CREATE PROC dbo.TransferCompanyInfo
    as
    BEGIN TRAN
    Update Data_Archive.dbo.Company
    Set 
    Data_Archive.dbo.Company.CompanyID = b.CompanyID,
    Data_Archive.dbo.Company.CompanyName = b.CompanyName,
    Data_Archive.dbo.Company.Address1 = b.Address1,
    Data_Archive.dbo.Company.Address2 = b.Address2,
    Data_Archive.dbo.Company.Address3 = b.Address3,
    Data_Archive.dbo.Company.Address4 = b.Address4,
    Data_Archive.dbo.Company.ZipCode = b.ZipCode,
    From Data_Archive.dbo.Company a, OLD.dbo.Company b
    Where a.CompanyID = b.CompanyID

    ELSE
    INSERT INTO Data_Archive.dbo.Company
    Select 
    CompanyID,
    CompanyName,
    Address1,
    Address2,
    Address3,
    Address4,
    ZipCode,
    FROM OLD.dbo.company 
    where not exists (select Data_Archive.dbo.Company.CompanyID from                   Data_Archive.dbo.Company
    WHERE CompanyID = OLD.dbo.Company.CompanyID)



    IF @@ERROR <> 0
                BEGIN
                    ROLLBACK TRAN
                    RAISERROR ('Error occured while copying data to TachographData_Archive.dbo.company', 16, 1)
                    RETURN -1
               END

     IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
         BEGIN
               COMMIT TRAN
               RETURN 0
         END
```

Comment: You should look into `Merge`.

Comment: What indexes do you have on your table?

Comment: No indexes atm, I just want to get it working to send over the data first

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Answer (score 3):

You could use [MERGE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) for this:

```
MERGE Data_Archive.dbo.Company WITH (HOLDLOCK) AS a
USING OLD.dbo.Company AS o
    ON a.CompanyID = b.CompanyID
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE    
    SET CompanyName = o.CompanyName,
        Address1 = o.Address1,
        Address2 = o.Address2,
        Address3 = o.Address3,
        Address4 = o.Address4,
        ZipCode = o.ZipCode
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN 
    INSERT (CompanyName, Address1, Address2, Address3, Address4, ZipCode)
    VALUES (o.CompanyName, o.Address1, o.Address2, o.Address3, o.Address4, o.ZipCode)
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN DELETE;
```

This will update any records that exist, insert any new records, and delete any records from the archive that have been deleted from the `OLD` database. If this last bit is not required then simply remove `WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN DELETE`.

Using `HOLDLOCK` will ensure that you do not meet a [race condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition), although MERGE does still have [some quirks](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/), I don't think they will be an issue here.

The main benefit of this is that SQL Manages this in a single transaction, so you don't need to check if one part failed and then roll the transaction back.

Comment: Thanks Gareth this looks much more efficient

Answer (score 1):

Use the `MERGE` statement:

```
MERGE INTO Stg.Data_Archive.dbo.Company AS tbl
USING (
    SELECT old.CompanyID, old.CompanyName, old.Address1, old.Address2, old.Address3, old.Address4, old.ZipCode
    FROM OLD.dbo.Company AS old
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Data_Archive.dbo.Company AS new
    ON old.CompanyID = new.CompanyID 
    WHERE new.CompanyID IS NOT NULL) AS source
ON tbl.CompanyID=source.CompanyID
WHEN MATCHED THEN --if i find a row, update
    UPDATE SET
    tbl.CompanyID = source.CompanyID,
    tbl.CompanyName = source.CompanyName,
    tbl.Address1 = source.Address1,
    tbl.Address2 = source.Address2,
    tbl.Address3 = source.Address3,
    tbl.Address4 = source.Address4,
    tbl.ZipCode = source.ZipCode
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN --if not, insert a new one
    INSERT (CompanyID, CompanyName, Address1, Address2, Address3, Address4, ZipCode)
    VALUES (source.CompanyID, source.CompanyName, source.Address1, source.Address2, source.Address3, source.Address4, source.ZipCode);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
BEGIN TRY
      SET NOCOUNT ON
      DECLARE @l_numberOfRecordsInserted INT       
         BEGIN
               RAISERROR ( N'Invalid Application User ID %d passed.'
               ,17
               ,1
               ,-1 )
         END
      IF NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 
                          1
                      FROM
                          Data_Archive.dbo.Company
                      WHERE
                          ( CompanyID  = @i_CompanyID  )
                          AND CompanyName = @vc_CompanyName ) 
         BEGIN
               INSERT INTO
                   Data_Archive.dbo.Company
                   (
                    CompanyID,
                    CompanyName,
                    Address1,
                    Address2,
                    Address3,
                    Address4,
                    ZipCode
                   )
            Select  CompanyID,
                    CompanyName,
                    Address1,
                    Address2,
                    Address3,
                    Address4,
                    ZipCode
                      FROM OLD.dbo.company 
    where not exists (select Data_Archive.dbo.Company.CompanyID from  Data_Archive.dbo.Company
                                    WHERE CompanyID = @i_CompanyID)


         END
      ELSE
         BEGIN
              Update Data_Archive.dbo.Company
                            Set 
                            Data_Archive.dbo.Company.CompanyID = b.CompanyID,
                            Data_Archive.dbo.Company.CompanyName = b.CompanyName,
                            Data_Archive.dbo.Company.Address1 = b.Address1,
                            Data_Archive.dbo.Company.Address2 = b.Address2,
                            Data_Archive.dbo.Company.Address3 = b.Address3,
                            Data_Archive.dbo.Company.Address4 = b.Address4,
                            Data_Archive.dbo.Company.ZipCode = b.ZipCode,
                            From Data_Archive.dbo.Company a, OLD.dbo.Company b
                            Where a.CompanyID = @i_CompanyID

         END

      RETURN 0
END TRY        
--------------------------------------------------------         
BEGIN CATCH        
    -- Handle exception        
      DECLARE @i_ReturnedErrorID INT
      EXECUTE @i_ReturnedErrorID = dbo.usp_HandleException @i_UserId = @i_AppUserId

      RETURN @i_ReturnedErrorID
END CATCH
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a `Merge` statement instead.  I believe this should work for you:

```
Merge Into Data_Archive.dbo.Company As Target
Using
(
    Select  CompanyID,
            CompanyName,
            Address1,
            Address2,
            Address3,
            Address4,
            ZipCode
    From    OLD.dbo.company 
) As Source On  Source.CompanyID = Target.CompanyID
When Not Matched Then 
    Insert (CompanyID, CompanyName, Address1, Address2, Address3, Address4, ZipCode)
    Values (Source.CompanyID, Source.CompanyName, Source.Address1, Source.Address2, Source.Address3, Source.Address4, Source.ZipCode)
When Matched Then
    Update
    Set     CompanyName = Source.CompanyName,
            Address1    = Source.Address1,
            Address2    = Source.Address2,
            Address3    = Source.Address3,
            Address4    = Source.Address4,
            ZipCode     = Source.ZipCode
;
```